# Lagrangian - solving differential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

From the Euler-Lagrange, I arrived at the following equation:

$$m\frac{\mathrm d^2X}{\mathrm dt^2} + V'\bigl[(X(t)\bigr] = 0.\tag{1}$$

I have 2 confusions now.

**Question 1:** How does one approach solving it ? is it the requirement that we should already know what $V(x)$ is before starting to solve it ? how do I solve it for when ball falling ? $\:\:V(x) = mgx\:\:\:\:\:$ ($x$ considered vertical).

**Question 2:** The official Lagrange equation is:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\frac {\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\right) - \frac {\partial L}{\partial x}=0\tag{2}$$

How do I arrive to this from eq. (1)?

Sorry if I'm asking very confusing question, just trying to fill the dots in my head.

Comment: Have you computed $V’$ when $V=mgx$? If so, you should be able to solve the differential equation.

Comment: Didn’t you get to (1) from the “official” equation by assuming a particular form for the Lagrangian? Why do you think you can go backwards to something more general?

Comment: What I'm asking is where equation (2) came from. I arrived to (1) by minimizing KE - PE and never encountered (2) when I was deriving (1)

Comment: Eq. (2) comes from requiring a generic action $S=\int L(x(t),\dot x(t))\, dt$ to be stationary $(\delta S=0)$ under a small variation $\delta x(t)$ in the trajectory.

Comment: It's strange, the book shows it derived equation 1 but can't use it to solve object falling problem. V(x(t)) = mgx(t), but then I can't move forward

Comment: Why can’t you compute $V’$?

Comment: @Ghoster at first glance, you could say that V' = mg, but is it really ? if so all I get is $ma = -mg$. https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/nsm10/PrincLeaAc.pdf check here(scroll down to find: "appendix: motion..." and you will realize it doesn't use (1) and still assumes stuff

Comment: Yes, $V’=mg$. The falling equation is therefore $d^2x/dt^2=-mg$ with solution $x=x_0+v_0t-\frac12gt^2$ where $x_0$ and $v_0$ are constants of integration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147246/discussion-between-chemistry-and-ghoster).

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772264/2451

Answer (score 1):

**1.**
Yes, you need $V(x)$ beforehand. Here you have $V(x) = mgx$, hence $V'(x) = mg$, so that the Euler-Lagrange equation $m\ddot{x} + V'(x) = m\ddot{x} + mg = 0$ is equivalent to the usual equation of motion $\ddot{x} = -g$ of a free falling body. Then you solve it as any ODE in order to find $x(t)$.

**2.**
Actually, the process usually goes the other way, i.e. Eq. $(2)$ $\Rightarrow$ Eq. $(1)$, since $L = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2 - V(x)$ in a standard setting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. I might add to ask you if you don't mind, how do I arrive/derive E.q (2) ?

Comment: @Chemistry Eq. $(2)$ comes from the minimization of the action functional $S[L] = \int L \,\mathrm{d}t$ (hence the so-called "principle of least action", which is the foundation of classical mechanics ultimately), where $L$ is the Lagrangian of the physical system. The Euler-Lagrange equation is derived by setting the functional derivative of the action $S$ to zero (in the same way as the optimization of a standard function); the functional derivative is sometimes called the "Euler-Lagrange operator", but you will need to refer to the theory of calculus of variation in order to go further.